# Is there a request/validation rule that would throw an error in case of unexpected input?

Tags: php, laravel, input, request, laravel-request

Something like `Request::only()` that throws an error if there is any extra/unexpected field in the request?

E.g.:

```
$request->strictly(['username', 'password']);
```

that would throw an error if POST request contains fields 'username', 'password', and 'foo'?

In case there isn't, what would be the best way to perform such a verification manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `strictly` method in the request class using [Macro](https://pineco.de/using-request-and-response-macros/)

`AppServiceProvider.php` and inside `boot` method add this method

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

public function boot()
{
     Request::macro('strictly', function(array $paramaters) {
       $array = array_diff(request()->keys(), $paramaters);
        if (count($array) > 0) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages(
                collect($array)->map(function ($row) {
                    return [$row => 'not needed'];
                })->collapse()->all()
            );
        }
      });
}
```

Now You can use this method inside the controller or request class

```
request()->strictly(['username', 'password']);
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it could be simplified a bit using array_diff(), like `if (count(array_diff(request()->keys(),$parameters)) > 0)) { throw...`

Comment: @YourCommonSense you can edit this answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i updated my answer with throw a message

Comment: This is a good solution. At what point would you do that if you're using a FormRequest validation? Can it go in the `after()` method, or will that not work because it's already been passed through the `rules()` method at that point?